# Find the iframe that called a function in its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, air

I have several iframes on a page that display <strike>ads</strike> unicorns/bacon to users. Because its not possible to detect an iframe's domready event via the parent (please let me know if this isn't true) I have some initialization-code in each iframe like this:

```
<body data-controller="unicorn">
    <!-- content -->

    <script>
        var $ = parent.jQuery;
        if($ && $.frameReady){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.frameReady(document);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The `parent` `document` has code very similar to the following ([about this technique](http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/) via @Paul Irish):

```
var frames = {
    // the following is irrelevant to my question but awesome.
    "unicorn": function (document) {
        var script = document.createElement("script"),
            element = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        script.src = "http://www.cornify.com/js/cornify.js";
        script.onload = function () {
            // defaultView is the DOMWindow.
            document.defaultView.cornify_add();
            $(document).click(document.defaultView.cornify_add);
            script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
        };
        element.parentNode.appendChild(script, element);
    },
    "bacon" : function(document) { /** mmm, bacon **/ }
};
// relevant but boring...
$.frameReady = function(document){
    var controller = $(document.body).data("controller");
    controller && frames[controller] && frames[controller](document);
};
```

Here is an [example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHPbm/2/embedded/result/) ([you can edit it here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHPbm/2)). It works great (at least it does in Chrome dev).

Now what I would LIKE to do is get rid of the `data-controller` bit in the iframe and instead use the `id` (or `data-*` or whatever) of the actual iframe element that is in the parent document to initialize the code.

If I could query the DOM via `DOMWindow` it would look like this:

```
$.frameReady = function(document){
    var iframe = $("body").find(document.defaultView),
        controller = iframe.data("controller");
    controller && frames[controller] && frames[controller](document);
};
```

Luckily, I only need this to run on webkit based browsers, Adobe Air 2.5 actually (but I'm testing in Chrome ATM).

Because S.O. answerers like it when a Question has a question here it is:

**Is there any (efficient) ways to query the DOM via `document` or `window` in webkit-based browsers - including Adobe Air 2.5?**

Comment: +1 for unicorns/bacon.  At least it has nothing to do with *ads* ;)

Comment: I think I spent more time implementing the unicorns in the example than trying to solve my own problem. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found that one iframe containing the unicorn for you

```
console.log(
        $("iframe").contents().filter( function(){
           return this == document
        }).length
);
```